# reading a file in a subdirectory

Tags: c, file, directory, fopen, opendir

I'm given a path to directory with mutiple subdirectories. Every subdirectory has a file with name "st". I'm trying to read every st file from every subdirectory but I always receive a NULL pointer when calling fopen ???

My code:

```
int main(){

DIR *dir;
struct dirent *ent;
FILE *st;

dir=opendir("/home/me/Desktop/dir/");

while( (ent=readdir(dir)) != NULL ){

    if(ent->d_type == DT_DIR && strcmp(ent->d_name, ".") != 0  && strcmp(ent->d_name, "..") != 0 ){

        DIR *subDir = opendir(ent->d_name);

        st = fopen("st", "r");

        if(st == NULL){
            perror("doesn't exist");

        } 

    }

}
closedir(dir);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the name in `end->d_name` is just the name of the "file" inside the directory, it's not the complete path, which means your call to

```
DIR *subDir = opendir(ent->d_name);
```

tries to find the directory in the process *current* directory.

You need to take the path you passed in to the first `opendir` call and append the new path part.

Comment: do I then even need to creat another direcotroy pointer (DIR *subDir) or can I just change the first one (DIR *dir)?

Comment: Neither. Just concatenate the names.

Comment: Root problem - chronic inability to do any debugging.

Comment: @Matthew If you don't have another `DIR*` for the subdirectory, you will overwrite the one you use in the outer `while` loop.